# Velocity vs time curve of negatively accelerating motor

Tags: acceleration, electric-current, voltage, power

I have a hopefully interesting yet simple question.

I want to plot the velocity vs time curve of a motor decelerating. The interesting bit is that the acceleration is going to be directly connected to the velocity of the motor, and I cannot figure out how to incorporate that into the equation.

**Information known:**

- Mass: 200kg
- Starting velocity: 2 m/s
- Back emf: 50 V/m/s
- Coil resistance: 0.9 ohm
- Force constant: 46.5 N/Arms

The idea is that I will short the windings to slow the motor from this speed, I can get all of the instantaneous stuff, but I know that there is a way to show this information over time without having to calculate it all by hand, I just cannot figure out the equation to use.

Thanks,
Green

Comment: If you plug in numbers you will probably be tagged as "homework question", it's better to use letters instead of numbers to keep the problem general.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're asking. Acceleration will always been connected to velocity.

Comment: What I mean is that the F from the formula for acceleration is calculated from the force constant of the motor for instance the motor at 2 m/s will generate about 100V (back emf  of 50V * 2m/s = 100V) which shorting across the coils gets you a current of 110A so at 2m/s you have an F of 5,115N but doing the same thing at 1.5m/s you will have a force of 3,875N.   What I am saying is that F changes as a result of velocity and I want to calculate that.

Comment: 46.5 N/Arms: what does that mean?

Comment: That is the force constant of the motor, so for every Amp (rms) through it generates 46.5 Newtons of Force.

Comment: The formula for Kinetic energy is K=(m*v^2)/2

Comment: 46.5 Newton's per Ampere,  root mean square. He's dealing with a linear motor.

Comment: Very astute observation docscience, these are indeed linear motors.

Comment: What about friction? Does your linear motor use a bearing? Friction from bearings can also, significantly affect your acceleration.

Comment: Friction is negligible from the bearings, I don't have exact numbers but I know that from 2 m/s the system will coast for well over 15-20m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand correctly, then the braking force is given by (with $v$ the velocity):

$$F=\frac{AB}{R}v$$
Where:
$$A=46.5\:\mathrm{N/A}$$
$$B=50\:\mathrm{V/m/s}$$
$$R=0.9\:\mathrm{Ohm}$$
Or:
$$F=kv$$
During braking the equation of motion is then (with $m$ the mass of the object):
$$ma=-kv$$
$$m\frac{dv}{dt}=-kv$$
Integrate:
$$m\int_{v_0}^{v(t)}\frac{dv}{v}=-k\int_0^tdt$$
$$\ln\frac{v(t)}{v_0}=-\frac{k}{m}t$$
So:
$$\Large{v(t)=v_0e^{-kt/m}}$$

Comment: I believe that this is what I am looking for yes, but for clarification... in the result the _m_ refers to the mass correct? I think everything else is clear, I just wanted to make sure

Comment: Which clarification?

Comment: _m_ in the result refers to the mass correct?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit that in now.

Answer (score 0):

Let the inital velocity be $v_0$ and the constant Force $F$, then the deceleration $a$ is

$$a=F/M$$

so the velocity $v(t)$ at a given time $t$ is

$$v(t)=a\cdot t + v_0$$

In your case $a$ is negative.

If $a$ is not constant but a function of $v$ and $v$ is a function of $t$ you will have to define your $a$ in terms of $t$ so that $a(v(t)) \to a(t)$ and integrate:

$$v(t)=\int_0^t a(t) \, \text{d}t+v_0$$

Depending on your function you may find it simpler to treat it as a differential equation and solve it numerically, then

$$x''(t)=f(x'(t)), \ x'(0)=v_0, \ x(0)=0$$

Comment: That is the question I had, what is the equation to integrate this, it has been years since I took calculus and cannot for the life of me figure out how to set up the equation to do this.

Comment: I added an update to adress this

Comment: So if I calculated out that a actually is equal to 12.92_v(t)_ would the integral change to:[this](https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=v(t)=$$\int_{0}^{t}&space;12.92v(t)dt&plus;v_0)